# Share an dockerized apache/php/mysql app without having to create a apache config file

Tags: docker, apache, containers

I created a simple todo list apache/php/mysql web app with 2 docker containers (one apache/php/code and one mysql). I then created an image on docker hub which embark the php code.

If someone wants to deploy my app, it has to :

- Create a docker-compose.yml file with the content I provide (maybe from Github)
- Create a .env file with mysql password, ports etc.
- Create a 000-default.conf file for apache vhost config
- Create a fullchain.pem and privkey.pem for https
- Run the docker-compose.yml

I'm not sure it is best practise to distribute a public app this way. I would like to simplify the process. I think I could first remove the need to create a 000-default.conf file but I really don't know how where to start. Any thought or advise would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT 1: following David comment :

The apache config file is very simple. It looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName XXXXXX
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
   
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName XXXXXX
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/privkey.pem
  SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I see two problems:

1. The SeverName changes according to the domain of the person deploying the application.
2. If the deployer doesn't provide a certificate, the container cannot start because looking for .pem files that don't exist.

Comment: The deployer will fundamentally have to provide their own credentials and certificates.  All of these steps seem necessary, except perhaps for the Apache configuration; what is in that file, and why can't it be bundled into the image you distribute?

Comment: Thanks so much David. I edited my question to give more informations. I understand about the credentials and certificates. I imagine I can manage these from my app (like a page to upload certificates and a page to modify the credentials).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to include the apache config into the Docker image.

1. Make a variable in the apache config file for ServerName and SSL paths:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ${SERVER_NAME}
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
       
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName ${SERVER_NAME}
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLCertificateFile ${SSL_CERT_FILE}
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ${SSL_KEY_FILE}
    SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

2. In Dockerfile, copy apache config:

```
COPY ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

3. Pass the value from .env file :

```
SERVER_NAME=mydomain.com
SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/apache2/ssl/fullchain.pem  # Uncomment if certificate provided into ssl folder
SSL_KEY_FILE=/etc/apache2/ssl/privkey.pem  # Uncomment if certificate provided into ssl folder
```

to docker-compose.yml :

```
environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME}
      SSL_CERT_FILE: ${SSL_CERT_FILE:-/etc/apache2/default_ssl/fullchain.pem}
      SSL_KEY_FILE: ${SSL_KEY_FILE:-/etc/apache2/default_ssl/privkey.pem}
```

4. Bind volume for SSL certificate provided by deployer

```
    volumes:       
      - "./ssl:/etc/apache2/ssl"
```

The apache config in the container takes the values provided by the deployer in the .env. If he doesn't provide certificate, it takes the default auto-signed one included into the docker image.